# como puedo sacar diferencia entre dias

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

buen dia 
tengo una duda
quiero sacar un script el cual me regrese a la pagina principal siempre y cuando ya aya cumplido dos dias
tengo un boton de editar entonces en mi taba hay una columna llamda fecha_regis
la cual tiene la fecha que se registro un nuevo permiso 
entonces quiero validar que solo me de dos dias y depsues me salga error ya no puedes editar mas
masomenos asi lo estaba haciendo
pero creo que lo que necesito es validar la los dias transcurridos para poder hacer el if

```
$fecha_regis="
  SELECT id, DATEDIFF(fecha_regis, NOW())  FROM perm ";
 if($fecha_regis < 2 ){
    echo 'No puedes volver a editar';
  }
```

muestro como es la conexion 
y un update que ejecuto normal sin prublema
    $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:4473', 'root', '', 'usuarios');

```
//si existe "id" en la url 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];//le asigno una variable 
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM perm WHERE id =".$id; //cadena de consulta para el elemento $id
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)){ //si obtengo resultados ejecutando la consulta anterior
        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ //asigno ese resultado a un array asociativo $user
            $comentarios = $usuario['comentarios']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $fecha_peticion = $usuario['fecha_peticion'];
            $nuv_labor = $usuario['nuv_labor'];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tambien intente esto 


SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    `perm` 
  WHERE 
    usuario ='Rmendoza'
  AND
    fecha_regis  >= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL +2 DAY)

Comment: Solo estás creando una consulta, pero no la ejecutas ni la lees; no puedes hacer la comparación así.

Comment: entonces como se podria

Comment: Ejecuta la consulta, lee el resultado y compara. Edita tu pregunta para agregar cómo es que te conectas a base de datos.

Comment: ya esta escrito en la parte de arriba

Comment: En los comentarios del código que agregaste tienes un mini tutorial para hacer la consulta, por favor inténtalo.